# Implementing multiple equals methods for a single class

Tags: java, equals, comparator

I have a class say

```
class Dog {
    String name;
    int age;
    String collarType;
}
```

I have already overridden `equals` method to compare all 3 fields to determine if 2 dogs are equal.

Now I have a situation where I have 2 `Dog` objects, and they can be equal even if the `collarType` of the 2 `Dog` instances are different. Therefore, I can't use my `equals` method.

Is writing a comparator with the new schema(compare only name and age) and checking if `compare(Dog d1, Dog d2)` returns `0` the best way to go about it?

Comment: For what purpose do you need to know if they're equal?

Comment: Guava has a class called [`Equivalence`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html), which can be used for this purpose.

Comment: To me this seems backwards: tests of equality should only use invariant fields such as name (low likelihood of change), date of birth (rather than age which can more readily change), and not collarType which can change on a whim.

Comment: It depends on the context in which you would want to compare `Dog` instances. If you want to sort them using a collection or similar, implementing a comparator is the way to go. If you just need an additional equals method, just implement it as an instance method of `Dog`. Of course, only the original `equals` method can be used using `==`, you would have to call your second equals by its name: `dog1.equalByNameAndAge(dog2)` or similar.

Comment: @gmazlami just to clarify, the == operator in Java never "calls" the .equals() method. == compares Object references or primitives.

Comment: @mangotang Perhaps they're thinking of Groovy, where `==` actually calls `equals` under the covers... Anyway, something else to consider with a separate instance method is when referring to a `Dog` instance by a super class like `Animal`, or even `Object`. That would still allow you to correctly call the primary `equals` method (since it's being overridden in Dog), whereas an `equalsByName` method would not be visible in that context.

Answer (score 1):

Equality is subjective to the user, as you have noticed. However, the only actual equality which is 'correct' should be the one on your object (and it's probably a full equivalence, since it would be weird to have a less strict version be correct). This equals should say that there is impossible, in any way imaginable, under any circumstance, object 1 and object 2 are different if they do equal.

Other ('subjective') equals methods should be achieved through a comparator, and yes, I do think that you should use a comparator. Moreover, you should name that comparator appropriately (like NameAndAgeComparator), to be distinct between, since you might also envision a DogRaceComparator and a SizeComparator to order by size.

You could (possibly) give your comparator a static equals method for ease, which would allow you to refer to it with static imports like *`equals(dog1,dog2)`*. But that is just my 2 cents

Answer (score 1):

Your class should look like this:

```
class Dog 
{
    final String name;
    final Integer age;
    final String collarType;

    public boolean equals(Object other) 
    {
       return this.name.equals(other.name) && 
              this.age.equals(other.age) &&
              this.collarType.equals(other.collarType);
    }
}
```

That puts your question in a starker category if any of these attributes are mutable.

If any of those fields are not relevant for equals then that should be a different `Type`.

public interface Named() { public String name(); }
public interface Aged() { public String age(TimeUnit timeUnit); }
public interface Collarable { public String collarType(); }

Then you have:

```
public class Dog implements Named, Aged, Collarable { /* brevity */ }
```

and provide *natural* `Comparator<Named>`, `Comparator<Aged>` and `Comparator<Collarable>` implementations of these interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

- Implement equals and hash code if you put it to any kind of Map or Set.
- Implement Comparable interface if you want to sort them but it should be compatible with the implemented equals and hashcode methods.
- Use Comparator implementation if you want to sort/compare the list by other field(s) than your equlas and hashcode method.